# Video embedding from any video sharing

Tags: youtube, embed

I have to design a web app where if you paste the link of particular video page from any video sharing site like "Youtube", "Metacafe" etc it should embed that video in the page. In simple words, what I was asked to do is that I have to embed a video from any site in my page.

Thanx in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can study the embed codes generated **by** YouTube and MetaCafe etc~ and then code something to mimic how they do it~

It seems like the **better** solution would be to allow people to paste the embed code generated by the site itself though. Since the hosters' conventions change.

Comment: I would agree with the suggestion but many end users feel dis comfortable ryt? Thanx again!!

Answer (score 1):

You could Try this:

```
<iframe height="500" width="500" scr="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoidentificationnumber/"></iframe>
```

Dont do this:

```
<object scr="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoidentificationnumber"></object>
```

You will need to make sure that when you click the submit button it gets the identification number from the end and putting it in the bit specified by videoidentificationnumber (I dont know how though).