# Is there any Jinja2/Django extension for video or pictures?

Tags: python, django, jinja2, youtube-javascript-api

I am building a website where I want to embed Youtube and other videos. Similarly it will also contain pictures from different websites. I am curious to see if there are any Jinja2/Django extension to embed pictures/video in a website? Or any library to handle the same.

This is a followup question for the question [video-embedding-from-any-video-sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150692/video-embedding-from-any-video-sharing)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [micawber](http://micawber.readthedocs.org), as it is a package designed specifically to get external rich content into your Python code. It has a decent [Django integration](http://micawber.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django.html) module.